# Capitalize the first letter of a string without touching the others

Tags: python, string, capitalize

I'm wanting to capitalize the fist letter of a string but leave the rest

What I have:
racEcar

What I want:
RacEcar

Answer (score 9):

Then just capitalize the first letter with `str.upper()` and concatenate the rest unchanged

```
string[0].upper() + string[1:]
```

Demo:

```
>>> string = 'racEcar'
>>> string[0].upper() + string[1:]
'RacEcar'
```

Answer (score 8):

You should do like Martijn suggests, but to make your function more robust, slice up to the first letter, so that you don't error on an empty string:

```
>>> rc = 'racEcar'
>>> newrc = rc[:1].upper() + rc[1:]
>>> newrc
'RacEcar'
```

so define a function that does this:

```
def capfirst(s):
    return s[:1].upper() + s[1:]
```

and then:

```
>>> capfirst(rc)
'RacEcar'
>>> capfirst('')
''
```

Comment: Unless you *want* there to be an error if the string is empty, of course.

Comment: If that's truly an error condition, then of course, but I like to code to the [Robustness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle)

Answer (score -4):

This has already been stated but I decided to show it.

Using `capitalize()` does what you want without extra work. For example,

```
def Cap1(string):
    # will not error if empty, and only does the first letter of the first word.
    return string.capitalize()
```

Using `title()` may require extra work if you have multiple words. For example,

let's assume your string is: "i want pizza"

```
def cap2(string):
    return string.title()
```

The output would be: "I Want Pizza"

Another way you can use `upper()` is:

```
def cap3(string):
    if not len(string) == 0: 
        return string[0].upper()
```

Comment: This answer is misleading: as the OP has shown, `capitalize()` does not only make the first symbol uppercase, but also the rest of them lowercase